# IsNan equivalent in C

Tags: javascript, c

I have a piece of Javascript code and i am trying to convert it into C code. I have a problem to convert following line to C:

```
var q = (!isNaN(dLat/dPhi)) ? dLat/dPhi : Math.cos(lat1);
```

Can you tell me equivalent of isNan in C?
Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to determine if is not null? if so check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872323/method-call-if-not-null-in-c-sharp

Comment: I am trying to determine that if its not a number(isNan).Can you please tell me how to use isnan function in C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On first sight, it looks like the original author just wanted to check for `dPhi` being 0, so you might want to substitute that. However, if you want to translate the code verbatim, simply use the [`isnan`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/isnan.html) macro from math.h, like this:

```
#include <math.h>

double q = (!isnan(dLat/dPhi)) ? dLat/dPhi : cos(lat1);
```

Comment: This line gives following error:

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
I am using Visual C++ 6.0

Comment: That sounds like there is a typo in one of the preceding lines. Try reproducing the problem with as few lines possible (say, 10, including the main function). If that doesn't solve it for you in the process, please ask a new stackoverflow question and include the full code.

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested on first sight:
        if (dPhi == 0)
  q = cos(lat1R);
 else
  q = dLat/dPhi;
thanks.

Comment: Substituting `if (dPhi == 0)` makes a difference if it's possible that either `dLat` or `dPhi` is a NaN. In the original Javascript, `cos(lat1)` is returned when either input is a NaN.

Comment: The check (dPhi == 0) is not the same! The expression dLat/dPhi becomes only NaN if dPhi == dLat == 0 or dPhi == dLat == infinite or as @SteveJessop mentioned one or both are NaN. For example 5/0 is infinite and not NaN.

Answer (score 6):

C has an `isnan` macro in `math.h` (this is a C99 addition).

The macro return an non-zero `int` only if the argument is a NaN value.

Answer (score 3):

Don't feel foolish, but it's:

```
isnan(x)
```

You can also use `fpclassify` and check if the return result is `FP_NAN`.

`isnan` was first introduced in 3BSD but didn't go into the cross-platform spec until C99. `fpclasify` turned up in C99. They're in `math.h`.

Microsoft supply `_isnan` in MSVC, in `float.h`.

Comment: is there a function like `isnan` in C89?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your C implementation is modern (i.e. anything but MSVC) you should have `isnan` available in `math.h`. Otherwise, `if (x!=x)` is a perfectly good way to check for NAN if you don't care about it modifying the floating point exception flags (which almost nobody uses or cares about).