# C++ add values of a vector that might contain NaN values

Tags: c++, nan, stdvector

I am a C++ noob.

What I am trying to do is sum the values of a vector of doubles (let's call it `x`) and ignore any values that are NaN. I tried to look this up, but I couldn't find anything specifically referencing what would happen if a vector contains any NaN values.

E.g.:

```cpp
// let's say x = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, nan, 4.0]
y = sum(x) // y should be equal to 10.0
```

Would the `accumulate` function work here? Or would it return `NaN` if `x` contains a `NaN`? Would a for loop work here with a condition to check for if the value is `NaN` (if yes, how do I check if `NaN`? In Python, the language I know best, this kind of check is not always straightforward).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if a double (or float) is NaN in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c)

Comment: Use the isnan macro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240138/isnan-equivalent-in-c

Comment: Once NaN gets into the sum it will be sticky.  You need to write your own `sum` and use [`std::isnan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan) to skip NaN values.

Comment: Any valid number + NaN  == NaN; Filter-out all your NaNs before performing accumulate, or make summation by hand in the loop while checking for `std::isnan`. You can also use `std::accumulate` with your custom binary operator, but to make this operator implementation-robust you would need to do unnecessary checks for both lhs and rhs.

Answer (score 3):

[`std::isnan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan) returns `true` if the passed floating point value is not a number. You have to add this check to all functions to avoid including NANs in your calculations. For example for `sum`:

```
constexpr auto sum(auto list) {
    typename decltype(list)::value_type result = 0;

    for (const auto& i : list) {
        if (!std::isnan(i)) { // < - crucial check here
            result += i;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hjb6v4x9z):

```
int main() {
    auto list = std::array{ 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, NAN };
    std::cout << sum(list); //prints out 6
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use std::accumulate with a custom summation operation.

```
const std::vector<double> myVector{1.0, 2.0, 3.0, std::nan("42"), 4.0};

auto nansum = [](const double a, const double b)
{
  return a + (std::isnan(b) ? 0 : b);
}

auto mySum = std::accumulate(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), 0.0, nansum);
```

Comment: Typical mistake mentioned in the docs: your sum will be casted to int if you run this operation on a vector with some decimal values. Correct version: `std::accumulate(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), 0.0, nansum);`